# Best way to get date difference with an accuracy of a tenth of a second

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datediff

I have a table with two dates and a float value that is the difference of the two dates in seconds (with 1 decimal point.)

This is what i am using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    --timestamp and id
    [start] datetime    NULL,
    [end]   datetime    NULL,
    [dif]   AS          ROUND(datediff(millisecond,[start],[end])/1000.0,1)
)
```

Apart from this being relatively large it doesn't seem like it's very efficient. Is there a better to do the same thing? like: `datediff(secondtenth,[start],[end])/10.0`

Comment: Your expression is fine.  The only real issue is overflow issues, if the return value would be too big to store in an integer.

Comment: Why store `diff` column at all?? Can't you calculate this during run time?

Comment: I think your approach of using a calculated field is ok BTW

Comment: -avoiding overflow is potentially tricky - what ranges of dates are you working over?  The range it can work over is not that great, you don't seem to be able to get a millisecond time difference over more than a few weeks - it isn't just storing the value, it is also a question if datediff can deliver the millisecond difference

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is extremely unlikely that the two dates will be more than 1 hour apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that gets around some potential overflow problems, any gap of more than approx 23 days will give datediff an overflow it seems, but this would would work for decades

```
declare @start as datetime;
declare @end as datetime;

set @start = '20100701 10:10:10.125';
set @end = '20100702 10:10:10.225';

select round((cast(@end as float) - cast(@start as float)) * 24 * 3600, 1);
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

with this test I see almost no difference in performance, this is for 10 million calculations, both sets take 13 seconds on my PC

```
declare @start as datetime;
declare @end as datetime;
DECLARE @MS as float;
DECLARE @I as int;


SET @I = 0;

SET @START = getdate();

WHILE @I < 10000000
BEGIN

    SET @MS = round((cast(getdate() as float) - cast(@start as float)) * 24 * 3600, 1);
    SET @I = @I + 1;
END

PRINT @MS;

SET @START = getdate();
SET @I= 0;

WHILE @I < 10000000
BEGIN

    SET @MS = ROUND(datediff(millisecond,@start,getdate())/1000.0,1)
    SET @I = @I + 1;
END

PRINT @MS;
```

Comment: So when use `CONVERT(float, <some datetime value>)` you get the number of days passed from the first day of the 20th century?

Comment: And is this faster than my method?

Comment: @nickzoum perhaps it would be better for you to check if it is faster?!

Comment: Numerical calculations with floats and dates should be fast.  i'd be surprised if you would see any performance uplift from the change - do you see the present calculation as a performance hit?  The benefit I was hoping to show was to eliminate numerical overflow risks.

Comment: Tested both ways for 1 million entries, This method took took 1 more second ( 25 vs 26 ) to complete (5 trials exact same results).

Comment: in that case, it has not delivered what I accept was your primary aim of speeding up the process.  I was hoping my solution was 'better' in that it is less liekly to fall victim to numerical overflows, although you said later that 1 hour is pretty much an upper bound for time differences, and that will not cause an error.

Comment: I would have considered this as a better alternative if the difference wasn't this small.

Answer (score 0):

This is not SQL Server specific, but ANSI SQL, and supported by a lot of DBMS-s.

First - DATETIMEs are usually not the data types to get fractions of seconds. I'd use TIMESTAMP for this, with the default scale of 6 (microsecond), as from the ANSI standard.

Having said that, we also have TIMESTAMPDIFF() in addition to DATEDIFF(). But the *datepart* possible is either `second` or `millisecond` or `microsecond`. So tough luck here.

Workaround is to divide the integer returned by TIMESTAMPDIFF() by 100 and hard-cast that result back to integer. Now some DBMSs truncate to FLOOR(*number*)::INTEGER a number with decimal fractions when doing that. If MS SQL does that, just add 0.5 to the division by 100 before hard-casting. It is in any case much, much faster than a ROUND().

And I use `the_start` and `the_end` as column names to avoid reserved words and remain within the ANSI standard. (*liberté, égalité, portabilité* ...)

See here:

```
WITH foo(the_start,the_end) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:31:26.016270',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:31:43.190093'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:31:51.952073',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:31:52.091006'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:32:10.305528',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:32:35.460201'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:32:35.460201',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11 07:32:35.599238'
)
SELECT
  the_start
, the_end
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(millisecond, the_start,the_end) AS diff_ms
, CAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(millisecond, the_start,the_end)/100 AS INT) AS diff_tenth_sec
FROM foo;
the_start                 |the_end                   |diff_ms|diff_tenth_sec
2017-01-11 07:31:26.016270|2017-01-11 07:31:43.190093| 17,174|           172
2017-01-11 07:31:51.952073|2017-01-11 07:31:52.091006|    139|             1
2017-01-11 07:32:10.305528|2017-01-11 07:32:35.460201| 25,155|           252
2017-01-11 07:32:35.460201|2017-01-11 07:32:35.599238|    139|             1
```

Happy playing - 
Marco the Sane

Comment: TIMESTAMP (as used in your example) and TIMESTAMPDIFF are not available in SQL Server. TIMESTAMP exists as a datatype, but it's a datatype that has nothing to do with date/times - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx )

Comment: Thanks, Chris - always happy to learn new things .... especially where the ANSI standard is supported, and to what degree ... Marco